# Making a print of a canvas img

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-canvas

I am trying to create a button that when clicked:

1. opens a canvas img in a new window;
2. starts the print function;
3. closes the new page after using JS.

This is what I have so far:

```
    function printCanvas() {
        var canvas = document.getElementById("sidstemoned");
        var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
        var newWin = window.open("");
        newWin.document.write('<img src="' + img + '" />');
        newWin.print();
        newWin.close();
    }
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#print_canvas').on('click', printCanvas);
    });
```

Canvas:

```
<canvas
 class='costumor_statistic col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12'
 style='height:350px;'
 id='sidstemoned'></canvas>
```

Button:

```
<button
  class="btn btn-default hidden-print"
  id="print_canvas">Print <span class="fa fa-print "></span></button>
```

The console prints this when I press the button:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property `toDataURL` of `null`
>
> at printCanvas
>
> at HTMLButtonElement.
>
> at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:4)
>
> at HTMLButtonElement.r.handle (jquery.min.js:4)

Comment: Can you just quickly point to what issues /errors you encountered along the way using the above code?

Comment: Could you edit your question by all your markup and scripts? My script works correctly

Comment: @Antonio Done updated the question to the code you send so now this is how i looks now on the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does it work correct?

```
function printCanvas() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvasname");
    var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    var newWin = window.open("");
    newWin.document.write('<img src="' + img + '" />');
    newWin.print();
    newWin.close();
}
```

**UPD:** Maybe you try find canvas before it was added to DOM. Try to wrap your onClick handler to `$(document).ready`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#print_canvas').on('click', printCanvas);
});
```

Comment: For me it works good:  open window with image from canvas,  open a print dialog,  close window

Comment: Thanks for the fast response, but sadly i couldn't get it to work so i am updating my question to shed some light on the situation.

Comment: No still nothing happening.

Comment: Well now it works for some reason, so thanks for the help.@Antonio

Answer (score 0):

The current problem is that the variable `canvas` you are using in the `printCanvas` function is `null`, which means that when you tried to fetch the element with:

```
document.getElementById("sidstemoned");
```

Nothing was found, and therefore in the second line, instead of accessing an element from the DOM, this is happening:

```
null.toDataURL("image/png");
```

`null` does not have a `toDataURL` property (or function), that is why you get that error. So just make sure that your variable `canvas` has an element associated to it, i.e. the id `sidstemoned` you are referencing exists in the document. You can verify that `canvas` has something by simply consulting its `length` property:

```
if(canvas.length !== 0) { /* remaining code goes here */ }
```

Also, non-directly related, you may want to delete the extra `class` attribute in the button (the one with a single `costumor_statistic`).

Comment: Okay i tried to move the script from the footer to the page where the button and canvas is located, after that it stopped to show the errors in the cconsole, also i am trying the script that Antonio gave me with the $(document).ready part.I tried the IF statement you wrote with an echo "Hello" in it on both footer and the page where the canvas is and it showed the hello, on both pages. @CPHPython

Comment: @ErikD good, so that means that now you have an element in your `canvas` variable's value. If any of these answers solved the problem you can accept one by clicking on the check mark on the left side of the answer. For [opening new windows in JS, this is a good reference](http://www.javascript-coder.com/window-popup/javascript-window-open.phtml), and if you have questions related to that, you may open a new question in here again.

Comment: Well it still doesn't work something is wrong, as it will not open a new window with the canvas img and start the print function, as a side note i have updated the start question, to show how it looks right now.

Comment: @ErikD your question purpose was to solve the problem that caused the error, which you accomplished. For this question to be useful to someone else, it should remain as it is... Manipulation of a new window object is a bit different from what you are trying to do, that is why I referred you to the previous link. If you also notice the [`window.open` documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open) and if your goal is to open an image on a new window, you should provide the URL, file or "any other resource supported by the browser" in this `open` method.

Comment: sorry maybe i explained it wrong but it all works now with the script from Antonio i think it was the bootstrap class in the canvas that did something to the script but it works now and thanks for the help.